# how do I combine two 3d real time graphs into one?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

Using `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`, I made two 3d real-time graphs.
I want to combine the two graphs into one.

When I tried to find similar examples, I could only find examples of 3d graphs, not "3d real-time."
How do I combine two 3d real-time graphs into one?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/random_walk.html):

```
...

def update_lines(num, lines):
    # Set data for each plot separately
    for line in lines:
        # NOTE: there is no .set_data() for 3 dim data...
        line.set_data(...) # Set data X and Y
        line.set_3d_properties(...) # it just means to set data on Z axis
    return lines

...

# Prepare 3d plot for each of your graphs
lines = [ax.plot([], [], [])[0] for _ in plots]

# Creating the Animation object
# Pass lines as an argument to FuncAnimation [fargs]
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, update_lines, num_steps, fargs=(lines), interval=100)
```